# add a new string for each observablecollection item

Tags: c#, list, observablecollection

I have an observablecollection of type Inventory
defined as

```
Observablecollection<Inventory> inventory = new ObservableCollection<Inventory>();
```

inventory has :

```
inventory.name;
inventory.status;
inventory.place;
```

How can I add some string at index[0] of every inventory like this:

```
["icescream", inventory.name, inventory.status, inventory.place];
["popcorn", inventory.name, inventory.status, inventory.place];
["popcorn", inventory.name, inventory.status, inventory.place];
["lollipop", inventory.name, inventory.status, inventory.place];
["candy", inventory.name, inventory.status, inventory.place];
```

is this possible?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. Can you clarify what your desired output is? the final "code" block isn't legal c#.

Comment: You mention the word "object" in your comments, but the example is too vague to give you an answer. Also, I do not think answers to this question would provide any value for other visitors in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

suitable linq expression might look like the following:

```
var joined = inventory.Select(item => new {value = "Test " + item.name, item});
// than for e.g. you could iterate through and print them out
foreach (var anonymousItem in joined)
{
    var item = anonymousItem.item;

    const string format = "[\"{0}\", {1}, {2}, {3}];";
    Console.WriteLine(format, anonymousItem.value, item.name, item.status, item.place);
}
```

Comment: actually, I dont want to output it in the console. I still want to query those data and pass around as an object.

Comment: Are you looking for a another collection which can do self update when the first one is updated and also still can hold an additional value for "Test#"?

Comment: yes and no. i have a collection that is fixed - in this case, named inventory. I want to add a new item in front of it based on the other item in the inventory collection ( some logic involved). maybe I need a new collection to hold the new string and the fixed inventory collection?

Comment: You can produce a new collection from old one where each item will hold a calculated string value and a reference to the original item, for e.g. anonymous class as new { Value = "string calculated", Item = item }

Comment: hold calculated string value and reference to the original? can u give an example?

Comment: So you only need to do inventory.Select(item => new {Value = youCodeToCaluclateValue(), Item = item })

Comment: what Value and Item do?

Comment: This is a properties (fields) in the Anonymous class they just hold the passed values, "Item" will hold your original item value from original collection "inventory" and "Value" will hold any result you going to calculate for that item

Comment: Here the link to Anonymous types description: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Comment: and here here the link to LINQ examples http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-09787825